# Props object is empty with history.push

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, query-string

I have an `onClick` handler used for filtering data that routes back to the same component, but with a different url.  However, when this same components renders again, I cannot access `props.location`.

Lots of code has been left out for brevity.

Component:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(props) // Empty
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props) // Empty
  })

  const handleFilter = argument => {
    history.push('/filter'); // 'argument' left out to test routing, and to ensure props.location is accessible
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleFilter('someArgumentHere')}>Filter</button>
  )
}
```

Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ exact, path, component: Component }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      exact={exact}
      path={path}
      render={props => (
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Component {...props} />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
};

<Router>
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact component={Dashboard} path="/" />
    <PrivateRoute exact component={Dashboard} path="/filteredPriority" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

When I click on `handleFilter`, the routing works.  Meaning, my browser navigates from `'/'` to `'/filteredPriority'`, and I see the same content, which is desired.  But, since this is a filter, I want to access the url params via `props.location`, and it's empty.  I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Needed to wrap my `Dashboard` component in [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).